# Regexes for Google App Engine

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I want to review the URL routing for my appengine webapp:

```
routes = [
        (r'/', CyberFazeHandler),
        (r'/vi/(eyes|mouth|nose)', CyberFazeHandler),
        (r'/realtime', RealtimeHandler),
        (r'/task/refresh-user/(.*)', RefreshUserHandler),
        ('/ai', FileUploadFormHandler),
        ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler),
        ('/upload', FileUploadHandler),
        ('/generate_upload_url', GenerateUploadUrlHandler),
        ('/file/([0-9]+)', FileInfoHandler),
        ('/file/set/([0-9]+)', SetCategoryHandler),
        ('/file/([0-9]+)/download', FileDownloadHandler),
        ('/file/([0-9]+)/success', AjaxSuccessHandler),
        ]

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes,
            debug=os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Dev'
            ))
```

Does it look alright to you? Can you recommend an improvement? Should I use the `'r` prefix to my regexes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered using [named Route templates](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Route) instead of capturing regular expressions? It could make the code more readable. Consider

```
Route("/task/refresh-user/<username>", RefreshUserHandler)
```

instead of

```
(r'/task/refresh-user/(.*)', RefreshUserHandler)
```

for example. (Of course, I don't know what kwargs `RefreshUser` actually wants, but you can change the angle-bracketed part to the appropriate name.)

Comment: Thanks! The suggestion would definitely have the advantages of improving readibility and maintainability.